# What is the syntax for passing tempData to texbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is how you do it on a regular output

> name: @TempData["Name"]

But I want the value to be pass into a textbox

> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "textbox" })

Comment: You don't. You set the value of property `Name` in the controller before you pass the model to the view

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
@{
var name= @TempData["Name"];
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Name,htmlAttributes:new {Value=name})
```

Comment: Thanks good buddy, needed to pass data from one page to another and add it to a textbox. I know there is probably a better approach but this worked perfectly for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx

```
      <form action="/Home/InsertCustomer">
       <% if (ViewData["ErrorMessage"] != null) { %>
         The following error occurred while inserting the customer data:
        <br />
        <%= ViewData["ErrorMessage"] %>
        <br />
        <% } %>

        First name: 
       <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<%= ViewData["FirstName"] %>" />
       <br />
        Last name: 
       <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<%= ViewData["LastName"] %>" />
       <br />    
       <input type="submit" value="Insert" />
       </form>
```